# How do you control compatibility mode in HTML

Tags: html, internet-explorer

The standard build of PCs on my current site has 'Display Intranet sites in Compatibility View' set.

If I clear this option then the site I have written appears correctly, if it is set then the site does not appear correctly

So how can I say not to use compatibility mode in the header of my pages

Current header is as follows;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Consultant Triage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.blue-amber.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

</head>
```

Comment: You're missing some required elements of XHTML, I believe, such as a DOCTYPE definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following line in the header before the links

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

It must be the first meta tag